# Best way to handle long generation of file to download

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, user-experience, powerbi-embedded

I have web application that uses 3rd party API ([PowerBI API for Embeded reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to)) to generate/export file (page from report) for user to download.
App can wait up to 1 min for 3rd party API response. From UX blocking UI for user for all that time isn't good. Is there any other way to handle this long downloading?

From 3rd-party API I receive stream.

There are three steps to follow:

- Sending an export request.
- Polling.
- Getting the file.

On 2nd step I can track the export progress, but don't know how this can be applied for UI/UX.

Comment: Generally this is where you build some sort of notification system into your site. Your site would poll the server (or receive push notifications via something like web sockets or SignalR) and then when there's a notification available (such as "report ready to download") it will display it to the user, and from there they can go download the file. This notification system wouldn't be specific to any one page, rather it's generally integrated with the navigation system of the site. Though you could also used email notifications to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

While using `exportToFile` API to export report, there are some limitations that might be a reason for long downloading.

1. The number of Power BI exports is limited to 50 report pages per minute per capacity.
2. Concurrent request- `exportToFile` supports concurrent export job requests. A job that exceeds its number of concurrent requests doesn't terminate.
   Concurrency applies to pages within the report, a single report containing 10 report pages/tabs will not complete until each one is rendered individually. How fast this is will depend on the capacity size.
3. Embedded Capacities- You need to have the reports hosted within a workspace that is running within an embedded capacity. The larger the capacity the more reports you can run concurrently and your reports will render fast. You can refer to the link to find out the maximum concurrent pages for each SKU.

There is nothing to do with Polling for fast downloading. We can only track the progress and status of export to file Job by using PercentComplete and ExportState.

Please find the references here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to?tabs=gen2
https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-export-to-file-status#exportsta